# ¿Como podria optimizar este codigo?

Tags: php, archivo

Este codigo es para validar los archivos que se ingresan a una carpeta o directorio y en caso de que se encuentren ya en el directorio pues mandar un aviso, me gusta pero siento que se puede mejorar y bastante. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme me seria de mucho agrado.

```
$imagen = $_FILES['img'];
$nombre = $imagen['name'];

function subirimagen($imagen, $nombre){
$escaner = scandir('./carpetaprueba');
foreach ($escaner as $scan){
    if ($nombre == $scan) {
        $msg = '<h2>La imagen ya se encuentra dentro</h2>';
        break;
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'], "carpetaprueba/$nombre");
        header("Refresh: 3 URL=index.php");
        $msg = "<h2>La imagen fue subida correctamente</h2>";}
}
         return $msg;
}
```

Comment: ¿En qué te basas para tener esa sensación? ¿Por optimizar buscas compactar el código o hacerlo más eficiente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo necesitas saber si el archivo ya existe en el directorio, puedes usar [`is_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-file.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
function subirimagen($imagen, $destino){
    if (is_file($destino)) {
        return '<h2>La imagen ya se encuentra dentro</h2>';
    }

    move_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'], $destino);
    header("Refresh: 3 URL=index.php");
    return "<h2>La imagen fue subida correctamente</h2>";
}

// Ejemplo de uso
$imagen = $_FILES['img'];
$nombre = $imagen['name'];
subirimagen($imagen, 'carpetaprueba/' . $nombre);
```

Comment: @KuroMaster, en mi opinion (_podes tomarlo o dejarlo_) no deberías hacer una redirección/refresco dentro de una función cuya funcionalidad aparente es solo subir una imagen. Tal vez te convendría devolver `true` o `false`, o un arreglo con `['exito'=> true/false, 'msj'=> 'Bla bla']`. Luego dependiendo de este resultado, hacer la redirección/refresco